# Android Studio - Failed to refresh Gradle project - failed to find target 4.4w

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

[image]

I'm trying to move my project from eclipse into android studio so that I can start building an android wear app.  I exported the app from eclipse and imported it into android studio.  However, when I try and add the android wear app, I start getting the error message "failed to find target 4.4w" see screen shot.

When creating a brand new project, this error does not occur.  I noticed that i'm still running on android api 19 for external libraries, but I can't upgrade it since it can't find it.

The 4.4w is installed via sdk manager, why can't android studio see this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason, the wear project had '4.4w' as the build target, i updated this to 20 and the error went away.

Comment: @Allen In the build.grade file of your app